# NSArrayI length]: unrecognised selector sent to instance in JSON Data Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, uilabel

i created an App that contains JSON Data and the code i used is as below:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.webSpinner startAnimating];
NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/specific_post.php?post_id=%@",self.postId]];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
}
-(void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responsedata
{
if (responsedata.length > 0)
{
    NSError* error;
    self.webDictionary= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responsedata options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    self.webArray=[_webDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
}
self.headingString=[self.webArray valueForKey:@"post_title"];
NSLog(@"Heading %@",self.headingString);
[self.webSpinner stopAnimating];
self.webSpinner.hidesWhenStopped=TRUE;
}
```

Here Self.Webarray is My array and self.headLabel is my Label but when i run it, Shows error like"`[NSArrayI length]: unrecognised selector sent to instance`".

Comment: please tell `self.webArray` output.if self.webArray is array then you should first get its index using `objectAtIndex` and then get `valueForKey`

Comment: check that self.webArray contains value or not

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani self.webArray is like as 
{
        "author_name" = "Parita Handa";
        "post_date" = "2014-12-17 13:25:13";
        "post_id" = 2885;
        "post_title" = "\U0aaa\U0abe\U0a97\U0ab2 \U0aae\U0abe\U0ab8\U0acd\U0aa4\U0ab0";
        "post_title_slug" = "%e0%aa%aa%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%97%e0%aa%b2-%e0%aa%ae%e0%aa%be%e0%aa%b8%e0%ab%8d%e0%aa%a4%e0%aa%b0";
        "post_views" = 121;
    }

Comment: then its NSDictionary not an array. you are telling webArray is your array but output looks like it is dictionary. follow @nburk's answer. and put debug point and check at which line it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this code is making the problem.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.headLabel.text=[self.webArray valueForKey:@"post_title"];
}
```

because `[self.webArray valueForKey:@"post_title"]` may not be a string value. So either check whether it is a string value or convert  it to a string value.

```
 -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        self.headLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.webArray valueForKey:@"post_title"]];
    }
```

Try this code.

Comment: It Contain Null Value When my Json Data Was Parsed then how it Contain Null Value?

Comment: Try a null check before setting the text of your headLabel.

Comment: If your JSON data contained a null value, then the parsed JSON will contain [NSNull null]. In this case, look at the error message that you got. You've got an array where you expected a string.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your code you are calling `length` of an instance on `NSArray`, this is what the error message tells you:

```
NSArrayI length]: unrecognised selector sent to instance
```

This is because `NSArray` doesn't have a method called `length` and thus doesn't know how to react to your command which causes the app to crash. If you want to know the number of objects within an `NSArray` you should use `count` instead of `length`.

`length` is what you use to get the number of characters in `NSString` or number of bytes in `NSData`. `NSArray` is a *collection* class, like `NSDictionary`, to retrieve the number of elements contained in a collection, `count` has to be used.